# Explode each values of Array element

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have an array like :

```
Array
(
   [2] => 2,6
   [3] => 1
   [4] => 14
   [5] => 10
   [6] => 8
)
```

I want to explode each element of an array and return a new array using array_map, so that I can avoid using loop, and creating extra function to call back.

O/p should be like :

```
  Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2
        [1] => 6
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 14
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 10
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
    )

)
```

Comment: So where are you stuck with using `array_map()`? Also you know that at the end `array_map` will also loop over your array.

Comment: *avoid using loop, and creating extra function to call back* - `array_map` also uses callback function as its first argument

Comment: @Alok Jha Did you tried my answer?

Comment: avoid using loop, and creating extra function to call back - Means , as we have function explode already , so not to create other function

Comment: @mohit, Yes its work for me, Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
$result = array_map(function($val) {
    return explode(',', $val);
}, $input);
```

Which will result in

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )

)
```

This will work on PHP >= 5.3 with support for anonymous functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do

```
$result = array_map('str_getcsv', $input);
```

This will also result in

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 14
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following code

```
$newArr = array_map(function($val, $key){
    return explode(",", $val);
}, $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(2 => '2,6',3 => '1',4 => '14',5 => '10',6 => '8');

foreach($data as $key => $val) {
    $new = explode(',',$val);
    $data[$key] = $new;
}
$output = $data;

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Comment: I dont want any extra loops, as we have array_map

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!